# How to do Polygon spatial search in Solr?

Tags: lucene, solr, geospatial, solrnet

We are using Solr 3.3 with Solr.NET and we have put a dynamic "location_p" location type field on our documents and now we need the ability to do spatial searches.

I have got the radius searches (distance from a given point) working like this;

```
{!geofilt sfield=location_p pt=33.882518712472255,-84.05531775646972 d=1.7}
```

Now we need the ability to do a Polygon squery to get all documents with the "location_p" field 'inside' a given set of Points (something along the lines of the Polygon search capabilities of [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/geo-polygon-filter.html)).

This is really different than the BBox query filter as the points of the Polygon are not symmetrical, more random based on user 'click' points.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Solr doesn't currently implement polygon spatial search.

There are a couple of efforts towards implementing this ([SOLR-2155](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2155), [SOLR-2268](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2268)). Try applying one of these patches, test it, contribute to the project.

There's also [Spatial Solr plugin](http://www.searchworkings.org/ssp), which implements polygon search but is only compatible with Solr 1.4.

See also http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/SpatialProposal

Comment: We just moved to ElasticSearch its using lucene as its index engine as well and supports GeoPolygons.

Comment: You can use the Spatial Solr plugin 2.0 with Solr 3.x too. The jar you can download from [here](http://www.searchworkings.org/ssp) works out of the box with Solr 3.x. You can also easily upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0 version, without the need to reindex. We are still using it despite of the spatial support provided by Solr.